# Efficient Image Resizing

Tags: java, android, image, memory, scale

In short, is the following an inefficient way to rescale images in any way perhaps due to garbage collection?

```
playBg_ = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res_, R.drawable.field);
playBg_ = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(playBg_, screenWidth_, screenHeight_, false);
```

And would it then be better to do something like this?

```
Bitmap tempBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res_, R.drawable.field);
playBg_ = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBmp, screenWidth_, screenHeight_, false);
tempBmp.recycle();
```

Or is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: check this topic [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the second method was required. The first method left too much memory wasted before garbage collection could get to it. I also found that I definitely need to call recycle on all my images prior to loading up new ones. Simply dereferencing them and expecting garbage collection to pick it up is not sufficient. I was constantly running out of memory due to this fact.

Answer (score 1):

You can read your logcat output by installing [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) on your eeePad.

Comment: Oh? That might come in handy. Thanks!!

Comment: Fyi, aLogcat doesn't work for JellyBean unless you root. Luckily, my tablet was Ice Cream Sandwich. My errors were indeed out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Second way is better. But why are you decoding the Bitmap by yourself and changing its size?

If you want to display it as a background, just use

```
myBgView.setBackground(R.drawable.field);
```

on your activity parent view.

Comment: That was one example. I have multiple images that are not backgrounds.